# flex/actionscript question

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
var n:Number = 0;
[1,2,3].forEach(function (x):void {
    n+=x;
});
```

how to do it in flash?
Flash throws error "function called with 3 arguments ..." 
i need only one argument here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Array.forEach() waits a function as first parameter which looks like this:

```
    function callbackFunc ( item:*, index:int, array:Array ) : void
```

You have to declare in your function all of the three parameters. So your stuff should look like this:

```
    var n   : Number = 0;
    var arr : Array  = [1,2,3];

    arr.forEach(function (item:*, index:int, array:Array):void {
        n+=index;
        trace( "n: " + n )
    });
```

You can't use the [1,2,3].forEach form in actionscript, because the compiler will see it as a bad metadata and throws an error.

Comment: it's too big declaration to use such cool thing as Array.prototype.forEach ^(

Comment: This is the way using properly Array.forEach in ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your [1,2,3] is an array.  In that case do it like this.

```
var d:Array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var v:int;
var n:Number =0;

for each(v in d )
{
    n+=v;
    trace(n);   
}
```

This outputs : 1 3 6 10 15

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
var n:Number = 0;
var ar:Array = [1,2,3];

for each(var i:Number in ar)
{
    n += i;
}

trace(n);
```

Comment: yes, but i want solution with forEach method, as it exists in javascript too.

Comment: I'm confused; this does use the for each method.

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach, not "for each" loop